How would I understand these ASN.1 elements (IMPORTS, OBJECT IDENTIFIER and IDENTIFIED BY) and parse them?
I am working on an ASN.1 PHP parser and I have implemented 85% of the ASN.1 features (excluding PER, XER and JER). I am having trouble understanding the following ASN.1 elements in a module.
IMPORTS: I know that you can import from fellow ASN.1 modules possibly loaded into memory but how would one load these modules into memory and how would an ASN.1 parser interpret this?
OBJECT IDENTIFIER and IDENTIFIED BY: I have this implemented in the parser but I'm having trouble understanding how it could be parsed if part of a module or used with IDENTIFIED BY, is the value encoded differently or?
I have been reading the OSS documents regarding ASN.1 parsing but I still have no idea how I'm going to implement this, if anybody can explain to me how this would work, it would be of great help.

Firstly, deep respect for taking on such a project!
IMPORTS is a key word that instructs a parser to fetch the definition of a PDU or value from another file. I'm pretty certain the convention is that the module that defines the the PDU or value is in a file of the same name, and that that file is in the same directory (or at least with some tools, in a directory identified on the command line as containing files that may be IMPORTed).
It also seems to be the convention that if you do import a PDU, but then make no use of it in the PDUs in your file, it's dropped and does not form part of the parser's output.
A possible approach is to recursively call ones own parser for each import, possibly with a means of identifying imported PDUs as such so that if they do not get using in any of the top file's PDUs, they can be dropped.
I hesitate to delve into the topic of object identifiers! They're extensively covered in Olivier Dubuisson's book.
